# the same view as Consul UI on CLI: see all failing checks from Consul cluster

Tags: curl, consul

I login to a host and see this hosts failed checks

```
# curl -s http://localhost:8500/v1/agent/checks | python -m json.tool | grep -B5 critical
        "Node": "hostwrefr5.local",
        "Notes": "Disk usage checking Warning: 5% - Critical: 2%",
        "Output": "DISK CRITICAL - free space: / 3044 MB (67% inode=85%); /dev 910 MB (100% inode=99%); /run 831 MB (90% inode=99%); /sys/fs/cgroup 920 MB (100% inode=99%); /home 451 MB (99% inode=99%); /var/log 0 MB (0% inode=99%); /var/log/audit 426 MB (94% inode=99%); /opt 221 MB (99% inode=99%); /boot 362 MB (71% inode=99%); /tmp 1382 MB (99% inode=99%); /usr/local 221 MB (99% inode=99%); /var/lib/consul 865 MB (95% inode=99%);| /=1482MB;4553;4697;0;4793 /dev=0MB;864;891;0;910 /run=88MB;874;901;0;920 /sys/fs/cgroup=0MB;874;901;0;920 /home=0MB;462;477;0;487 /var/log=712MB;691;713;0;728 /var/log/audit=25MB;462;477;0;487 /opt=2MB;227;234;0;239 /boot=145MB;482;497;0;508 /tmp=4MB;1405;1449;0;1479 /usr/local=2MB;227;234;0;239 /var/lib/consul=43MB;926;955;0;975\n",
        "ServiceID": "rdgd/disk-usage",
        "ServiceName": "rdgd/disk-usage",
        "Status": "critical"
```

I am searching a CLI command for all failed checks in the whole consul cluster.

Something like you see on Consul UI (all nodes failing or all services failing)

￼[image]

Our Consul UI is protected by HTTP Auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a check that can list [services by status](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/health.html#health_state) in the datacenter.

> **/v1/health/state/<state>**
>
> This endpoint is hit with a GET and returns the checks in the state
>   provided on the path.

You'll need to query it once for each state and each datacenter you are interested in.

Comment: thanks. example `curl -s -k https://example.com/v1/health/state/critical | python -m json.tool`